# Generic Type Class initiating

Tags: java, generics

We write a library that use generics, i am not sure how to create an instance of generic type. Shortly how to write create method?

```
public class Lib<V extends Base> {

    private HashMap<Integer, V> map = new HashMap<Integer, V>();    

    public V get(int key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public void add(int key, V value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public void create(int key) {
        // V v = new V();  // ?? How to implement this line
        // add(key++, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you truing to create?

Comment: That is not possible,

Comment: (You might want to remove that static field.) (Edit: Oh, I'll do it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use new with a generic type; generics in java have type erasure. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

There are a couple of dirty ways to acquire an instance of your generic class though; for example: -

```
void create(Class<V> foo)
{
    foo.newInstance(); // Create a new instance of generic type V
}
```

Alternatively, you could create foo as a private member and do this without having to pass 'type.class' to the method whereby you pass the class in the constructor: -

```
class bar<V>
{
    private Class<V> baz;

    private V qux;

    public bar(Class<V> foo)
    {
        baz = foo;
    }

    void create()
    {
        qux = baz.newInstance();
    }
}

bar<Integer> quxx = new bar<Integer>(Integer.class);
```

As others have said, you can create a factory that will do this for you. There's another stack overflow post that has further information [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: FFS, don't use reflection for this. (Thankfully, Java is good enough to prevent your code compiling.

Comment: Is the down vote entirely necessary? I've already suggested that a factory can be used to do this and provided a link to a question that has an up voted answer for resolving this using a factory..

Comment: Suggesting using reflection for this is dangerous. Yes it deserves downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

From a language point of view, there are no guarantees that `V` has a non-throwing, accessible, no-args constructor. The standard way to deal with this situation is to introduce an Abstract Factory as in, for instance, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434505/4725).

Comment: @TomHawtintackline your approach is simply stunning! Thx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider @Tom Hawtin - tackline answer. It is the best and the approach is simply beautiful! All it takes is to add another factory implementation all the time, but it's quiet small payment.

```
  public class InstanceOfGenericClass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          new GenericClass<VPassed>(new FactoryImpl()).createInstance();
      }
  }
```

//------------------------------------------------------------

```
 class GenericClass<V>{

     private final Factory<V> factory;
     public GenericClass(Factory<V> factory){
         this.factory = factory;
     }

     V createInstance(){
         return factory.create();
     }
 }
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------

```
interface Factory<V>{
V create();
```

}

//-------------------------------------------------------------

```
 class FactoryImpl implements Factory<VPassed>{
     @Override
     public VPassed create() {
         return new VPassed();
     }
 }
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------

```
class VPassed{}
```